# $(G/H)/(G/H)_t$ has rank $m-n$ where $G$ is finitely generated abelian and the rank of $G/G_t$ and $H/H_t$ is $m$ and $n$ respectively

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to prove , using the fundamental theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, that if $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group and $G_t$ is its torsion subgroup such that $G/G_t$ is of rank $m$ and $H$ is a subgroup such that $H/H_t$ is of rank $n$, then $(G/H)/(G/H)_t$ is of rank $m-n$. There is a solution [Rank of $(G/H)/(G/H)_t$ where $G$ is finitely generated abelian and $H$ is a subgroup.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777005/rank-of-g-h-g-h-t-where-g-is-finitely-generated-abelian-and-h-is-a-sub?rq=1) but its proof uses notions with which I am not familiar.

I could solve it by assuming that every subgroup of $G$ is a direct sum of factors each of which is a subgroup of the corresponding factors in the decomposition of $G$, but this is not true in general. What should I do?

Comment: Why do you assume that everyone will know what $G_t$ means?

Comment: I thought it was a standard notation for the torsion subgroup. I’ll edit my question @DerekHolt